# How does R-Studio recover thousands of deleted/"lost" files from a SSD with no free space

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

I have a Samsung 850 EVO for a Windows 7 64-bit boot drive, with a single partition. There were 14,478 JPEGS (as well as thousands of other files) in approximately 180GB of free space on the SSD, totaling just over 1GB. I copied PDF files to the SSD until there was no room left on the drive. I had assumed that the files would be overwritten. However, running R-Studio again found the JPEGS, and it was possible to view the majority of the them in the viewer.How is it that these files persist?

Answer (score 0):

The operating system may have made backup copies of this file in a number of different places. You may delete a file, but older versions of it may still be stored on disk as part of your operating system’s previous versions feature or other caches, or subsystems specially designed for recovery like volume shadow.

SSD's only default instant reaction to a deleted file is to forget where that file is rather than erasing it, so the files can actually sit scattered around an SSD for quite a while. Deleting files immediately would cause extra wear on an SSD, which is why it does not happen.

With modern solid-state drives, the drive’s firmware scatters a file’s data across the drive. Deleting a file will result in a “TRIM” command being sent (assuming the OS and SSD support this and it is enabled), and the SSD may eventually remove the data during garbage collection.

A good deletion approach would be to use the wiping utilities provided by the manufacturer, but with regard to all Windows backup systems.